# How to make Puppy Linux save state automatically

Tags: linux, puppylinux

I have Puppy Linux installed and booting from flash drive. If I pull the power instead of doing a normal shutdown I lose whatever hasn't been flushed from RAM. How do I make it so that any changes I make are saved automatically and won't get lost?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Puppy Linux to automatically save the state file after a certain amount of time
[This explains](http://www.pcguide.com/vb/showthread.php?66929-Puppy-Linux&s=3588b5cf4056f62b9c3d9382dab9806d&p=446722#post446722) how to set up this feature